# how to recognize a word like split

Tags: java, android, split, textview

I used this code to recognize $ symbol and set bold effect to all lines that have $ at the first of.

```
String[] Splited=mystring.split("\n");  
         String msg=""; 
            for(int i=0;i<Splited.length;i++){
               if(Splited[i].startsWith("$")){
                  msg=msg+"<b>"+Splited[i]+"</b>";
               }
               else
                  msg=msg+ Splited[i];
        }
```

my problem is that when I get output of this code using Html.fromHtml() all enters or \n are deleted and my texts are dammaged.
is there anything like split() that put texts in an array without deleting the \n and after proccess put every \n at the true place that they been there?
thanks a lot for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `<br/>` (HTML equivalent of `\n`) after `Splited[i]`.

i.e.:

```
msg += "<b>" + Splited[i] + "<br/></b>";
```

Answer (score 1):

> my problem is that when I get output of this code using
>   Html.fromHtml() all enters or \n are deleted and my texts are
>   dammaged.

HTML doest rec `\n`. if you want to go next line then use `<br/>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to encode the string to something like UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

As `split()` method take a regex expression as a parameter, you can use a look behind expression to check if you match the `\n` character:

```
String[] Splited=mystring.split("(?<=\n)");
```

It means  the regex is `true` when previous character is a `\n`